# Why is web page opened

Tags: google

I restored os on my android phone, and when I go to google browser(first time on fresh os), it opened some website that I haven't visited in years. I check all settings and can't find why I got that page... Why is this, and how can I fix it?

Comment: May be you once had enabled synchronization of browser data and later turned it off? Now on the new installation it is enabled again and you got your old data synced. That would be a potential reason.